# Port 80 used by Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Tags: skype, port, iis, sql-server, netstat

The port 80 is used by `Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0` and cannot be stopped. I have tried many solutions, but no one worked. Here is what I have done. Also, here is what is on the page :

```
Not Found

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

**IIS**:

Has been disabled, and it’s not installed on my system (was before).

**Skype**:

Don’t use the port 80, and it is close.

**netstat**:

On run of `netstat -ano | find ":80 "`, here what I have:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    192.168.1.142:50105    104.93.165.59:80       CLOSE_WAIT      2944
  TCP    192.168.1.142:50106    96.7.200.149:80        CLOSE_WAIT      2944
  TCP    192.168.1.142:50107    96.7.200.149:80        CLOSE_WAIT      2944
  TCP    192.168.1.142:50215    24.200.239.155:80      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.1.142:50216    24.200.239.155:80      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.1.142:50217    24.200.239.155:80      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.1.142:50218    24.200.239.155:80      TIME_WAIT       0
  some Chrome things here...
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
```

After removing `2944` (`WinStore.Mobile.exe`), and removed Chrome, we can only see the system (`4`) and `0` using this port.

**SQL Server**:

I don’t have the SQL Server installed, and nothing in "Services" is related to SQL.

I don’t know what to do, to make this port accessible for Apache installations. If you need more info, don’t hesitate to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: We'll need some more info.  After a reboot, is the mystery service still listening on port 80? Does `netstat -anob` return process names after that reboot?  What makes you think the port is being held by "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0"?  If you disable all 3rd party services and startups, is there still something listening on the port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there is an app still bound to port 80 on any interface (first line of netstat).

Try running command prompt as an administrator again and add the -b option (so,  `-anob`) and it should tell you what application is actually being bound rather than just that the port is in use.

Comment: They all return : _Impossible d’obtenir les informations de propriétaire_ that is `Unable to get the owner information`

Comment: "They all return : `Unable to get the owner information`"  Then you have a very large problem that goes beyond just something listening on port 80.

Comment: Not 100% its a big issue, just an issue! ... being PID 4, we can actually already tell that this is the system account. Next, try to see if you have any odd services you don't recognise as I believe a service running under system is binding to port 80.

Comment: @WilliamHilsum If "all" of them return that he can't get the owner info, then that seems like a larger, system-wide problem (to me anyway) -- may be an easily fixable big problem tho. ;)

Comment: @WilliamHilsum What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - I think all was an exaggeration - pid 0 is for the dead ones/no access, 4 is system, and the 2944 is probably genuine... You could be right, just don't think so from experience

Comment: @FelixINX - I recommend launching msconfig and looking at services tab (or going to services directly if you are comfortable), then disabling non microsoft ones and working out exactly what is binding to port 80.

Comment: "I think all was an exaggeration" I think so too (or just a translation problem), but the user hasn't confirmed either way. :)  Hey @FelixINX - when you say "all" were they ALL showing unable to get the owner, or just the port 80 ones?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Sorry for the "all", it is onlye the port 80 that have this issue.

Comment: Ahh, then it's because they're owned by the System (which has higher permissions than you) -- so as William and I have suggested: Use MSConfig to disable all 3rd party services and start-ups, and see if it's gone. If so, then start each thing you disabled (one at a time) until you find the culprit, then deal with the culprit. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have disabled **all* the non-Microsoft services, and the page is still there. No clue what is it. It must be a Microsoft program. Is there anything I can give to you (e.g. a list) to help you find?

Comment: It was finally Microsoft web deploy. Thanks to ­@WilliamHilsum